# How to scroll item by item in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scroll, horizontal-scrolling, smooth-scrolling

How to scroll item by item in horizontal RecyclerView?
I don't want to scroll or smoothScroll all of the items in RecyclerView.

Comment: most likely you need `android.support.v7.widget.PagerSnapHelper` if i understand your "item by item" correctly

Comment: That's true. I need android.support.v7.widget.PagerSnapHelper. Thank a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val snapHelper = PagerSnapHelper()
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
```

it really works, but you can also use the ViewPager for small lists

Comment: That's true. Thank a lot dear Mukhit